# Handling Multi-level custom taxonomy hierarchy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am trying to sort through a multi level hierarchy in a custom taxonomy.

I have custom taxonomy's with multiple sub taxonomy's. Eg:

```
Level1
-Level2
--Level3
```

ect

At the moment I can use `get_term_children()` to return the children for a top level taxonomy but this doesn't tell me anything about there position in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to run a cycle using [get_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) paired with the 'parent' attribute.

```
$args = array( 'parent' => 0 );
$parents = get_terms( array( 'custom-tax' ), $args );
foreach ( $parents as $parent ) {
    echo $parent->name;
    $args['parent'] = $parent->term_id;
    if ( $children = get_terms( array( 'custom-tax' ), $args ) ) {
        foreach ( $children as $child ) {
            echo $child->name;
        }
    }
}
```

You may be able to rewrite the "if ( $children..." into a while loop if you need more recursion than that.

Comment: That code only works for 2 levels, though I understand though how you could convert it across to multiple.  I was really looking to see if wordpress stored any data on the hierarchy.

Comment: It does, but I believe it does it through the 'parent' attribute, not a numerical representation of what level the term lives at.

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively create a hierarchical structure using this function:

```
function sort_hierarchical(array &$cats, array &$into, $parent_id = 0){

    foreach ($cats as $i => $cat) {
        if ($cat->parent == $parent_id) {
            $into[$cat->term_id] = $cat;
            unset($cats[$i]);
        }
    }

    foreach ($into as $top_cat) {
        $top_cat->children = array();
        sort_hierarchical($cats, $top_cat->children, $top_cat->term_id);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'category', 'hide_empty' => false));
$cats = array();
sort_hierarchical($terms,$cats) ;
```